# Generating an array of random numbers such that the numbers at the higher indexes are greater

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I am trying to generate an array of random numbers such that the numbers at the higher indexes should be greater than the numbers at the lower indexes.

For example, an array like this:

```
array = [1.5  1.7  2.4  5.6  8.5  8.9  9.2  9.5  10.2  11.3]
```

I can do this using:

```
array(1:10) = 0;       % Pre-allocation
array(1) = abs(randn); % Generating a +ve rand no.
for k=2:10
    array(k) = abs(randn) + array(k-1);  % adding a +ve rand no. to the previous value 
end
```

I am looking for a better (and/or vectorized) way!

Comment: Why not just to [sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) the array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myarray = sort(rand(1, 10))`

will do, I think

EDIT:

Although your question doesn't mention it, from your example you want positive numbers,

so 
   `sort(abs(rand(1, 10)))`

Will do you what you want.

Comment: wasn't expecting it to be that simpler! Thanks!